# Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 77

Tags: php

So I was working on my new project again, and suddently, I walk in to this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 77
```

So I went to line 77 of `index.php` and I saw this: (Line 76-77)

```
$page = 2;
$pageTemplate = $page->template;
```

So I checkt a few things, but nothing seems to be wrong. And before you ask, there is a value assigned to `$page->template;`

Any help from you guys?

Thanks,

Wesley.

Comment: PROBLEM : `$page` is not an object

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the variable $page to 2. It is now an int.

i.e. If it was an object beforehand, it has been overwritten.

```
//Creating object called Page.
$page = new Page();

//Overwriting the variable $page with an integer.
$page = 2;

//Error is thrown, simply because $page is now an int.
$pageTemplate = $page->template;
```